# Cannot import psycopg2 from python3 on fedora 27

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, fedora

I've just upgraded to Fedora 27, and have been unable to get psycopg2 working.

I'd very much appreciate any help anyone can provide.

As a simple test case, I've been executing
`>>> import psycopg2`
at the interactive shell. This works fine for Python 2.7, but fails for Python 3.x.

With **Python 3.4 and 3.5**, I get the message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'

With **Python 3.6**, I see:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/jazcap53/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 50, in 
>       from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
>   ImportError: /home/jazcap53/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so: symbol __res_maybe_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference

I installed Fedora 27 from DVD-ROM. I find psycopg2 packages located at
`/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages`
and
`/home/jazcap53/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

My Python packages were all either included with Fedora, or installed via `dnf`. They are:

```
python3-3.6.3-2.fc27.x86_64
python35-3.5.4-1.fc27.x86_64
python34-3.4.7-1.fc27.x86_64
python2-2.7.14-2.fc27.x86_64
```

Some packages I have installed that may be relevant are:

```
python2-devel-2.7.14-2.fc27.x86_64
python3-devel-3.6.3-2.fc27.x86_64
libpqxx-1:5.0.1-2.f27.x86_64
libpqxx-devel-1:5.0.1-2.f27.x86_64
libgcc-7.2.1-2.fc27.x86_64
postgresql-devel-9.6.6-1.fc27.x86_64
```

P.S.: If I'm asking this question in the wrong place, please direct me to the right place.

**Edit:**
I noticed that:

`/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/`
contains subdirectories
`psycopg2` and
`psycopg2-2.7.3-py2.7.egg-info`

but

`/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/` and
`/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/`
contain nothing related to `psycopg2`

and

`/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/`
contains subdirectory
`psycopg2-2.7.3-py3.6.egg-info`
but not `psycopg2` itself

Comment: Can you try `pip3 install psycopg2` or `pip install psycopg2`?

Comment: Thanks @NanduKalidindi for your reply.
`pip install psycopg2` gives me:
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
`pip3 install psycopg2` gives me:  
Requirement already satisfied:  
psycopg2 in /home/jazcap53/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may have noticed, each version of Python has its own package hierarchy. So the installation on Python 3.6 will not give you access on 3.4 and 3.5.

With that said, there seems to be some problem with the system's standard lib with Python 3.6. One solution to that could be to install without binaries, like this:

```
python3.6 -m pip uninstall psycopg2
python3.6 -m pip install --no-binary :all: psycopg2
```

To install `psycopg2` on 3.4 and 3.5 you would run these with or without the `--no-binary` option:

```
python3.4 -m pip install psycopg2
python3.5 -m pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Hallelujah!!! Thank you so much @HaraldNordgren!
Everything works now under python3.6 :)
For python3.4 and 3.5, though, when I run the above commands I get
`/usr/bin/python3.4: No module named pip`
pip seems to be working normally in other respects.
Can you tell me how to get them to work?

Comment: It seems then that `pip` is not installed for those Python versions. Pip is a module like any other, so again it's not shared between different versions. See instructions here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/, where all the `python` commands you execute need to be substituted by `python3.4` and `python3.5` respectively.

Comment: Thank you again @HaraldNordgren!
I did manage to get psycopg2 installed for python 3.5 and 3.4 with e.g.,  
`pip install -t /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages psycopg2`
This installed psycopg2 then errored out with  
`Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2-2.7.3.2.dist-info'`  
but I'll take it, considering I've spent 2.5 days on this :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have automatic installs / docker install you need to ensure you add the following line to requirements.txt to ensure psycopg2 installs from source, rather than using the binary, or you'll continue to experience the above issue upon deployment.

```
psycopg2>=2.7,<2.8 --no-binary psycopg2
```